# Can I create a prioritized synchronization lock with C#

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, locking, ipc

I'm currently using [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) to establish synchronized access to a file between processes as such:

```
//Process 1
//High frequency "writes"
try
{
    mutex.WaitOne(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

    try
    {
        //Do write operation

    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
catch(AbandonedMutexException)
{
    //Log error
}
```

and then at times I may need to check what has been written to a file:

```
//Process 2
//Low frequency "reads"
try
{
    mutex.WaitOne(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

    try
    {
        //Do read operation

    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
catch(AbandonedMutexException)
{
    //Log error
}
```

But what happens with this technique is that the `Process 2` that is doing low-frequency "Reads" seems to hang up and never receive access to the resource, or it may take too long to do so.

Is there a better lock to use in my situation?

PS. It must be compatible to be used between processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I fixed it by introducing an event:

```
EventWaitHandle event = new EventWaitHandle(true, 
     EventResetMode.ManualReset, 
     strEventGlobalName,     //Must be the same for each process
     out dummy, 
     eventSecurity);         //To allow access between processes
```

so then the writer will look as such:

```
//Process 1
//High frequency "writes"

//Wait to allow writing
if (event.WaitOne(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite))
{
    try
    {
        mutex.WaitOne(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

        try
        {
            //Do write operation

        }
        finally
        {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
    catch(AbandonedMutexException)
    {
        //Log error
    }
}
```

and the reader as such:

```
//Process 2
//Low frequency "reads"

try
{
    //Reset event to halt writing
    if (!event.Reset())
        throw new Exception("Did not reset event");

    try
    {
        mutex.WaitOne(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);

        try
        {
            //Do read operation

        }
        finally
        {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
    catch(AbandonedMutexException)
    {
        //Log error
    }
}
finally
{
    //Set event to allow back writing
    if(!event.Set())
        throw new Exception("Did not set event");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a named Mutex like this?:

```
bool created = false;       
string mutexHandle = "SOME_UNIQUE_ENOUGH_STRING_slkuhfwer7487rctcwf6gt86efcwwgsa";
var myFileLock = new Mutex(true, mutexHandle, out created);
```

Because only a named Mutex can be used to sync a task between processes at system level.

If so you are doing the right thing (technically).

But if you are performing high frequency operation on one end; you should provide a gap like `Thread.Sleep(1);` before `mutex.WaitOne(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);` in writer (for instance); or maybe you should use another approach like a memory mapped file, or write to new tagged files (by providing a time-stamp in the name and deleting read files) or using a tool that provides you versioning on your file.

Comment: No, it's a bad approach. There's no need to "slow down" one thread/process to make it work.

Comment: I did not say it's a bad approach. And since we have not something like "ReaderWriterLock" at system level (BTW ReaderWriterLock do favors Write operations over Read operations); by adding that "slow down" we provide an opportunity for the reader. And it's not all about locking. Maybe more data should be flushed into the file on each write instead of writing many tiny data many times. And if we want going really deep into optimizing this then we should write a (tiny) persistence layer for a database; for example considering the "pagesize" of the hard-disk and the like! :)